# Rails / Carrierwave: Multiple files get overwritten

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave

I'm following the instructions on https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/blob/master/README.md#multiple-file-uploads

Specifically this line is giving me trouble (I think):

```
<% user.avatars.each do |avatar| %>
  <%= hidden_field :user, :avatars, multiple: true, value: avatar.identifier %>
<% end %>
<%= form.file_field :avatars, multiple: true %>
```

I have a table called `properties` and a related table called `property_units` which are nested fields on property using the Cocoon gem.

the `property_units` have the carrierwave file column.

For my files input on the view, I have the following:

`_property_unit_fields.html.erb`

```
        <% if f.object.files.count > 0 %>
            <div class="uploaded-files">
                <% f.object.files.each do |file| %>
                    <%= f.hidden_field :files, multiple: true, value: file.file.identifier %>
                    <p>
                        <span><%= file.file.filename %></span>
                    </p>
                <% end %>
            </div>
        <% end %>
        <%= f.file_field :files, multiple: true %>
        </div>
```

`f` on the case above is from this Cocoon implementation:

```
    <div id="property_units">
     <%= f.fields_for :property_units do |unit| %>
        <%= render 'property_unit_fields', f: unit %>
      <% end %>
      <div class='links'>
        <%= link_to_add_association 'Add Unit', f, :property_units, class: 'button button--tertiary' %>
      </div>
    </div>
```

I'm able to save the file, and the mounted uploader works. I can save multiple, but if I upload again, the previous files are replaced entirely.

So for instance, I just uploaded a file called "tickets.pdf". This file is inside the database.

The hidden input is rendered as:

`<input multiple="multiple" value="tickets.pdf" type="hidden" name="property[property_units_attributes][0][files][]" id="property_property_units_attributes_0_files">`

Once I upload a new file, "tickets.pdf" will get erased.

What am I doing wrong?

Edit, here is the log from when it gets uploaded

The file that already exists and is referenced in the hidden input is the `tickets.pdf` and the newly uploaded file is the `ActionDispatch`.

So obviously, it's sending a string and Carrierwave expects a file. but this is what the documentation states to do. So I don't know what else is supposed to be placed in the request

```
"files"=>["tickets.pdf", #<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x00007fd6dc275118 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/tmp/RackMultipart20200415-3213-10sfy1b.pdf>, @original_filename="somefile.pdf", @content_type="application/pdf", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"property[property_units_attributes][0][files][]\"; filename=\"somefile.pdf\"\r\nContent-Type: application/pdf\r\n">], "_destroy"=>"false", "id"=>"1"}},
```

So now "somefile.pdf" is the only file I have and in the DB column it looks like `{NULL,"\"somefile.pdf\""}`

NULL being tickets

Comment: I ran into the same problem and for me it was solved by up updating carrierwave. Multiple file uploads were reworked for 2.0 and we were using an older version. See https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/issues/2393.

Answer (score 0):

You must process this logic by hand, Carrierwave does't have incremental multiple file uploads from box.

https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/wiki/How-to:-Add-more-files-and-remove-single-file-when-using-default-multiple-file-uploads-feature

Comment: The link I posted starts off with saying "CarrierWave also has convenient support for multiple file upload fields.". I'm not really sure how to do this logic by hand since these fields are part of nested attributes. And also on the link before the example, they write "If you want to preserve existing files on uploading new one, you can go like:"

Comment: can you send development.log when you try "Once I upload a new file, "tickets.pdf" will get erased."

Comment: sure one second. and also, here is what happens on the DB column: `{NULL,"\"somefile.pdf\""}`. It's happening because I guess I'm sending a string inside that hidden input. but thats what the documentation has.